# Command grouping (&&, ||, ...)

Tags: bash, syntax, operator-precedence

We are currently in the /home/student/ directory. We execute the following commands:

```
pwd; (ls) || { cd .. && ls student/; }  && cd student || cd / && cd ;
```

The commands that are executed are:
pwd, ls, cd student, cd /, cd

Here is what I think:

- pwd is executed, because it's the first command
- (ls) is executed in a subshell, because the commands are seperated
  with ";"
- the code on the right of || isn't executed, since the code on the
  left of || was executed

So far everything clear, I guess. But I have no idea why other commands are executed? If someone could break it down for me, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Operator precedence for `&&` and `||` is strictly left-to-right.

Thus:

```
pwd; (ls) || { cd .. && ls student/; }  && cd student || cd / && cd ;
```

...is equivalent to...

```
pwd; { { { (ls) || { cd .. && ls student/; }; } && cd student; } || cd /; } && cd ; }
```

...breaking that down graphically:

```
pwd; {                                      # 1
       {                                    # 2
         { (ls) ||                          # 3
                   { cd .. &&               # 4
                              ls student/;  # 5
                   };                       # 6
         } && cd student;                   # 7
       } || cd /;                           # 8
     } && cd ;                              # 9
```

1. `pwd` happens unconditionally
2. (Grouping only)
3. `ls` happens (in a subshell) unconditionally.
4. `cd ..` happens if (3) failed.
5. `ls student/` happens if (3) failed and (4) succeeded
6. (Grouping only)
7. `cd student` happens if either (3) succeeded or both (4) and (5) succeeded.
8. `cd /` happens if either [both (3) and one of (4) or (5) failed], or [(7) failed].
9. `cd` happens if (7) occurred and succeeded, or (8) occurred and succeeded.

---

Using explicit grouping operators is wise to avoid confusing yourself. Avoiding writing code as hard to read as this is even wiser.

Comment: can you reiterate, by code example, which is the format for using explicit grouping operators?  is that the oneliner that starts with `{ { {`?

Comment: @blamb, each `{` starts an explicit group, and each `}` ends one.

Answer (score 12):

> (ls) is executed in a subshell, because the commands are separated
> with ";"

`(ls)` is executed in a subshell because of the parentheses. Parentheses introduce subshells.

> But I have no idea why other commands are executed?

Unlike other programming languages you might be familiar with, bash does not give `&&` higher precedence than `||`. They have equal precedence and are evaluated from left to right.

If you had `a || b && c`, in other languages this would be read as `a || { b && c; }`. If `a` were true then neither `b` nor `c` would be evaluated.

In bash, though, it's parsed as `{ a || b; } && c` (strict left-to-right precedence), so when `a` is true `b` is skipped but `c` is still evaluated.