# bash: using || and && together

Tags: bash

Is there any way to use `||` and `&&` together in a single line command?

I'm looking to do something whose python equivalent would be:

```py
import os
doSomething() if os.system("[[ -f hello.txt ]]") else doSomethingElse()
```

Comment: The result is not identical. `a && b || c` **is not** the same as `if a; then b; else c; fi`. You get subtle bugs if you try to pretend that it is.

Comment: Specifically, you can have `c` run even if `a` is false, should `b` fail. And because `b` is marked "checked" by this idiom, `set -e`'s behavior is changed by it (not that using `set -e` is good practice).

Comment: (err, rather: even if `a` is true, should `b` fail).

Comment: Ah alright, got it! Btw, your answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29351665/command-grouping is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's no "AND" in your python example, is there?

In bash, I would write this simply as

```
if [ -f hello.txt ]; then
   doSomething
else
   doSomethingElse
fi
```

Comment: I would guess the OP put `&&` because of the short `[ -f hello.txt ] && echo 'foo'`