# if statements with more than one condition

Tags: bash, macos

Hi i'm just trying to write an if statement but with multiple conditions. I wrote using functions i'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it. Example in the check list i want make sure everything is good before proceeding further. Ensuring the app(s) is not already running, there is a User present, and Dock is running. If one or more items doesn't meet the requirements it will echo "something is wrong"

```
function appNotRunning {
    pgrep SomeApp && return 1 || return 0
}

function finderRunning {
    pgrep Finder && return 0 || return 1
}

if appNotRunning \
        && [ "$loggedInUser" != "_mbsetupuser" ] || [ "$loggedInUser" != "root" ] \
        && finderRunning ; then
                echo "everything pass"

      else

      echo "something is wrong"

fi
```

Comment: There's no need for `&& return 1 || return 0`. A function returns the exit status of the last statement. If you want to invert the status, use `! command`

Comment: Why not just `appNotRunning() { ! pgrep SomeApp; }`, and `finderRunning() { pgrep Finder; }`? -- note that the `function` keyword is something bash only supports for backwards compatibility with ancient pre-POSIX ksh; the modern standard (since the early 1990s) is `funcname() { ... }`.

Comment: You need grouping around the `||` condition.

Comment: a-yup. `&& { [ ... ] || [ ... ]; }`

Comment: ...I think we have a duplicate for that; going to hunt for it.

Comment: [compound if statements with multiple expressions in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267569/compound-if-statements-with-multiple-expressions-in-bash) is a _narrow_ interpretation; [Command grouping (&&, ||, ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29351665/command-grouping) is a wider one.